# Why does bootsnap kernel_require is failling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootsnap

I have a rails application that uses bootsnap, I am currently unable to run the app as I am getting an error from bootsnap.

The error is
`/Users/path/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in require: no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)`

And here is the `Kernel_require.rb` method that is failing.

```
def require_with_bootsnap_lfi(path, resolved = nil)
  Bootsnap::LoadPathCache.loaded_features_index.register(path, resolved) do
    require_without_bootsnap(resolved || path)
  end
end
```